# How to make a component (popup modal) appear only once using React hooks

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, next.js

I want to make a popup modal appear only once with localStorage (bs: the modal already appear when the page load). Is there a way to do this using hooks?

```
const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState<boolean>(true)

  return(
      <ModalIsContractor
        showModal={showModal}
        setShowModal={setShowModal}
      />
)
```

Comment: Could you clarify what the purpose of the modal is? E.g. display information, ask for preferences, confirm settings. because that can change whether/how you should use `localStorage`

Answer (score 0):

You could use several approaches:

1. The simplest one is having a global variable outside your component, which you can set to true in a useEffeft after mounting
2. Use useRef since the value will be persistent until the page is refreshed
3. If you want the “state” of your modal to be persistent even after refreshing, then better use localStorage, [here you can find an example of the useLocalStorage hook](https://usehooks.com/useLocalStorage/)